# Magento2 Multisite now loading store specific default_head_block.xml

Tags: magento2, xml, multistore

I have a magento 2.2.3 that I am trying to setup with a Multisite where each store view has a different child theme.  Now My workflow is that I work on a local MAMP version of the website I then upload to an external server that is a staging website.

My issue is when I go to a specific store view it is not loading the default_head_blocks.xml file that I have located in the child theme which enables me to call in storeview specific css, etc files

I have the file in

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child_theme_a/Magento_Theme/layout
```

However if I when I am in the default store view and I edit the default_head_blocks.xml file that is called into the default theme which is located at

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child_theme/Magento_Theme/layout
```

That store views xml file loads fine ?? so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Please check Your DB theme type.

> go to >> DB >> search theme in your Database

[image]